# Reading multi-line records

Tags: perl

Given the code data file content of each data records, I'm unable to print the first line of each record. However, it does print the first line of the first record as in: 1aaaaaaaaaaaaa

Special Note: I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but in my case, I need a solution that follows the code question....

Data file content of records

```
  1aaaaaaaaaa 
  aaaaaaaaaaa 
  aaaaaaaaaaa 
  __Data__ 
  1bbbbbbbbbb 
  bbbbbbbbbbb 
  bbbbbbbbbbb 
  __Data__ 
  1cccccccccc 
  ccccccccccc 
  ccccccccccc 
  __Data__

  { 
      local $/="__Data__\n"; 

      open my $fh,"<","logA.txt" or die "Unable to open file"; 

      while(<$fh>) 
      { 
        # remove the input record separator value of __Data__\n
        chomp; 

        # display the line of each record 
        if(/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/sm) 
        { 
           print "$1\n"; 
        } 
      } 
      close ($fh); 
  }
```

I get the undesirable output of:

```
  [root@yeti]# perl test2.pl    
  1aaaaaaaaaaaaa
  [root@yeti]#
```

I need the output of the first line of each record.....

1aaaaaaaaaaa
   1bbbbbbbbbbb
   1ccccccccccc

Answer (score 2):

To debug, you find where the state of the program diverges from your expectations, then you backtracking until you find the cause.

Checking what the program does reveals that your loop is only entered once and that `$_` contains the entire file. That means that Perl didn't find the line terminator (`"__Data__\n"`).

Examining the file finds spaces between `__Data__` and the newline. Remove the trailing spaces from your file.

```
perl -i -ple's/\s+\z//' logA.txt
```

Comment: did not work with an error of Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1. Plus I manually check for trailing spaces since the file is so small and get the same problem..

Comment: So you're saying the file you posted is different than what you used? Stop lying to us! Fix your question.

Comment: Thanks for your commits and I'm thinking the same thing, perl is not finding the input record separator...

Comment: I didn't need to try your code to identify your problem, but I did try i to make sure it was the only problem.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the extra help on this... Did you use my exact code?

Comment: I'm using perl version v5.10.1

Comment: Yes, and you don't use anything that's version-specific. Well, lexical file handles from 5.6

Comment: You are right, its only going through the loop one time. I added a loop count counter when the input record separator is set to $/="__Data__\n"; But when I set it to $/="__Data__", it goes through the loop normal of 4 times... Wow, this is weird...

Comment: In my above message, stackoverflow is formatting the code incorrectly and it may be by design...

Comment: Did you perhaps create the data file on Windows and running the script on unix (or cygwin)? You might have forgotten to convert the line endings, resulting in Perl seeing `__DATA__\r\n`

Comment: The problem is fixed. I recreated the file on a linux system and it works. I think I originally created this on windows. I can't thank you enough for hanging tough with me on this issue. I tested on the real data and that works as well...

Comment: Using the snippet I showed you on the unix side will clear those \r too.